# Trouble working with variables in python from different files. UnboundLocalError

Tags: python, file

In file a I have the following:

```
won = False
counter = 0
while(won == False):
    game.userY = setGameRow(row, counter)
    game.userX = setGameCol(col, counter)
    counter+=1
    printBoard(bd, game.userX , game.userY)
    move(row, col, bd, mines, game.userX, game.userY)
    won = retWon()
```

In file b I have:

```
userX = 0
userY = 0
def setGameRow(row, counter):
    if(counter == 0):
        userY = row-1
    return userY

def setGameCol(col, counter):
    if(counter == 0):
        userX = col-1
    return userX
```

It gives me the following error: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'userY' referenced before assignment

I tried doing some workarounds but I can't get it to work.

Comment: Ask yourself what happens in  `setGameRow()` when `counter > 0`. What value do you expect the function to return? If you expect the value of the *global* variable `userY` then your code should say so: put the declaration `global userY` inside the function.

Comment: Thanks for the help I finally solved it.